# Error parsing data JSON, Fragment Android Studio

Tags: json, android-studio, android-fragments

Someone please help me why my result always **error parsing data** ?
My app run smoothly but does not display anything. i feel so stuck here.
this is my code
Sorry for bad english

**API JSON**

```
public function getkategori2(){
    $data = array();
    $token = $this->input->post('f_token');
    $tabel = $this->input->post('f_tabel');

    if ($token == '' || $tabel == ''){
        $data['result'] = false;
        $data['msg'] = "Data Kosong";

        echo json_encode($data);
        return;
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tabel.'_kategori INNER JOIN files WHERE '.$tabel.'_kategori.id_kategori = files.id_kategori';
    $q = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($q->num_rows()>0) {

        foreach ($q->result() as $value) {
            $kategori = array(
                'nama_kategori' => $value->nama_kategori,
                'file_name' => $value->file_name,
            );
        };  
        $data['result'] = true;
        $data['kategori_data'] = $kategori;
        $data['msg'] = '';

    } else {
        $data['result'] = false;
        $data['msg'] = 'error';
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**JSON Result**

> {
>     "result":true,
>     "kategori_data":
>     {
>       "nama_kategori":"Pasta",
>       "file_name":"1_Pasta.jpg"
>     },
>     "msg":""
>     }

**KategoriAdapter**

```
public class KategoriAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KategoriAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Kategori> mData;
private Context context;
private SessionManager sesi;

public KategoriAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Kategori> mData){
    this.context = context;
    this.mData = mData;
}

@Override
public KategoriAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_list_kategori, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(KategoriAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Kategori k = mData.get(position);

    String kategori = k.getKategoriNama();
    String gambar = k.getImg();




    //masukan kedalam object viewholder
    holder.tvKategori.setText(kategori);



    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(Constant.BASE_IMAGE + sesi.getTabel() + "/kategori/" + gambar)
            .into(holder.ivKategori);

}

//buta object interface onAdapterjabatanListener
private OnAdapterListener listener;

//buat method untuk mendefiniskan listenernya
public void setListener(OnAdapterListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData == null ? 0 : mData.size();
}



//buat class yang extend dari ViewHolder
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public LinearLayout container;
    public TextView tvKategori;
    public ImageView ivKategori;

    public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        //baru hubungkan variablenya dengan item yang ada di class layout item
        container = v.findViewById(R.id.container);
        tvKategori = v.findViewById(R.id.tvKategori);
        ivKategori = v.findViewById(R.id.ivKategori);
    }
}
```

**KategoriFragment**

```
public class KategoriFragment extends Fragment {

SessionManager sesi;
private ArrayList<Kategori> data;
private OkHttpClient okClient;
private RecyclerView rvData;

public KategoriFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kategori, container, false);

    sesi = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    okClient = new OkHttpClient();
    rvData = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvData);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvData.setLayoutManager(manager);

    getData();

    return rootView;
}

private void getData(){
    data.clear();
    String url = Constant.BASE_URL + "getkategori2";

    FormBody parameters = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("f_token", sesi.getToken())
            .add("f_tabel", sesi.getTabel())
            .build();

    //buat request untuk ambil data
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(parameters)
            .build();

    okClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    e.printStackTrace();
                    RbHelpers.pesan(getActivity(),
                            "error :" + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call,final Response response) throws IOException {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //hilangkan dialognya

                }});
            final String responData = response.body().string();
            RbHelpers.pre("respon data : " + responData);
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //debug hasilnya kedalam android monitor
                    try {
                        //parsing json
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responData);
                            Log.d("tagJSON",json.toString());
                            //check hasilnya apakah true or false
                            boolean hasil = json.getBoolean("result");

                            if (hasil){
                                //ada datanya
                                //buat object jsonArray
                                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("kategori_data");
                                //looping data dan masukkan kedalam arraylist
                                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Kategori kategori = new Kategori();

                                    kategori.setKategoriNama(jObj.getString("nama_kategori"));
                                    kategori.setImg(jObj.getString("file_name"));

                                    //tinggal masukan ke arraylist
                                    data.add(kategori);
                                }
                            } else {
                                String msg = json.getString("msg");
                                RbHelpers.pesan(getActivity(), msg);
                            }
                            //tinggal masukin ke recylerview
                            //UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter
                            KategoriAdapter adapter = new KategoriAdapter(getActivity(), data);
                            rvData.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            RbHelpers.pesan(getActivity(), "Error parsing data");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        RbHelpers.pesan(getActivity(), "Error ambil data");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is the wrong part "kategori_data" is a JSONObject , not a JSONArray, Check the correct format in jsonBlob as

[image: JsonBlob Screen]

Here you have an example of a mine working project where i have a model Articulo(Product) and I make a request to retrieve that object data

```
   try{
                        // Get the JSON array

                        JSONObject result = response.getJSONObject("articulo");


                        int i ;
                        for(i=0;i<1;i++){
                            JSONObject articulo = result;
                             ListaArticulos item = new ListaArticulos(
                                    articulo.getString("IdArticulo"),
                                        articulo.getString("Precio"),
                                        articulo.getString("Stock"),
                                        articulo.getString("Consultas"),
                                        articulo.getString("IdCategoria"),
                                        articulo.getString("Descripcion"),
                                        articulo.getString("Observacion"),
                                        articulo.getString("Codigo"),
                                        articulo.getString("Imagen")


                            );
```

So in conclusion what you need to do is  change JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("kategori_data");

for

JSONObject jsonOb = json.getJSONObject("kategori_data");